# Rss Feeds Not Working

Tags: jquery, json, rss, google-api, feed

I am using the following google api to get feeds.

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&output=json&q=<URLHERE>
```

In my case query is

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&output=json&q=https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCP2UBhhA2k32TM8YiJkUTBg/feed
```

No data coming for this only message coming:

```
{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "Feed could not be loaded.", "responseStatus": 400}
```

What is wrong with the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd hit the wrong URL. The Google feed service needs some kind of RSS input, you just provided a ordinary HTML page. I've looked upon the right feed url

So the full url is:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&output=json&q=https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UCP2UBhhA2k32TM8YiJkUTBg/uploads?alt=rss

Comment: @DebasishMohapatra Please put in some effort... as is clearly shown, the API is deprecated in the meanwhile. Use YouTube API v3 for new projects. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/